# open map in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

1.How to open google maps in bootstrap modal, when the user clicks on the enlarge map button below the google map displayed.
[codepen link](http://codepen.io/rajumax/pen/zGWoQd)

2. Any possibility show that particular place in google map when  user clicks **view in google map** link in infowindow.

[image]

**JS**

```
     var storeArray = new Array(
     ["23.589242", "58.412586", "ST1"],["23.628695", "58.266483","ST2"],["23.622155", "58.488977","ST3"],
     ["23.239333", "58.312586", "ST4"],["23.151933", "58.312586", "ST5"],["23.609027", "58.538858", "ST6"],["23.608280", "58.538343", "ST7"],["23.607789", "58.538021", "ST8"],["23.606412", "58.537399", "ST9"]);

var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(storeArray[0][0], storeArray[0][3]),
  zoom: 9,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions); 

  function testmap() {

      for (i = 0; i < storeArray.length; i++) {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(storeArray[i][0], storeArray[i][1]),
            map: map
         });


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: storeArray[i][2]

    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker); 

      }

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', testmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdorLN

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var mapNode = map.getDiv();
    $('#map-canvas-modal').append(mapNode);
});
```

1. add a listener on your modal shown event
2. retrieve the node that contain the div of the map with the getDiv()
   function
3. append that node to your div inside the modal

P.S.: pay attention to not give the same id to more than one div. Ids must always be unique.